# ruler control error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, import, mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl-js

I'm having this issue even though I've done what mapbox asks to be done, but maybe I've missed something.

This is the link with the usage: https://bravecow.github.io/mapbox-gl-controls/   (I'm only trying to add the ruler control)

I'm trying to add a ruler to mapbox-gl, in the usage of mapbox says that I have to do:

```
npm install mapbox-gl-controls
```

and add

`<link href="mapbox-gl-controls/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">`

to the code, which I already did and added it to the main folder, I search more about the import and in some cases I need to add `{}` to the function that is going to be imported but it seems that there is something else.

```
import RulerControl from 'mapbox-gl-controls/lib/ruler';



map.addControl(new RulerControl(), 'top-right');


// events


map.on('ruler.on', () => console.log('ruler: on'));

map.on('ruler.off', () => console.log('ruler: off'));
```

the error message I'm getting is

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier"

Answer (score 1):

The error is due to the reason that you are not using `{}` in your `import` statement.

Try to change your import like this:

```
import { RulerControl } from 'mapbox-gl-controls/lib/ruler';
```

Hope it helps

You can find the docs for `import` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)